# Create @Query select without Entity table class

Tags: java, spring, boo

how should be looks like code which return Json from database without @Table(tableName) @Entity etc. ?
for example , that CustomResponse is not mapped to database table, but by that select I want
get same result as normal @Entity @Table class

```
    {   
      name : "myname",
      count: 5 
     }
```

---

```
@Query(value = """
            SELECT name,count from mytable            
            """
            ,nativeQuery = true)
    List<CustomResponse> getData();
```

---

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomResponse {
    private String name;
    private Integer count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [JPA constructor expresion](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#result_classes_constructor_expressions) :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new <add here CustomResponse class package name>.CustomResponse(m.name, m.count) FROM MyEntity AS m")
List<CustomResponse> getData();
```

Comment: ] [Incorrect syntax near '.'.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause.....
SELECT  NEW sk.example.java.CusomResponse(name,count) from blabla

have something like this :
new sk.t.t.entity.dto.response.data.CustomResponse(JSON_VALUE(clv.params,'$.label.localeStrings.sk')

Comment: Answer updated. I had forgotten 'AS'keyword in sql request

Comment: still doesn't work, same error, I using microsoft sql